# Bound for the Krull dimension of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

> Consider the polynomial ring $R[X]$ in one variable over a (not necessarily Noetherian) ring $R$. Prove  the following inequality: $\operatorname{dim}R[X] \le 2\operatorname{dim}R+1$.

In Bosch's book there is a hint saying:

> if $p_1 \subsetneq p_2 \subset R[X]$ are two (different) prime ideals in $R[X]$ restricting to the same prime ideal $p \subset R$, then $p_1 = pR[X]$.

- Let $d:=\operatorname {dim}R$, and take an ascending chain of  primes  $p_1 \subsetneq p_2 \subsetneq\dots \subsetneq p_n\subset R[X]$. If, for some index $i$, $p_i\cap R=p_{i+1}\cap R=:p$, then the chain around $i$ becomes $$\dots\subsetneq pR[X]\subsetneq p_{i+1}\subsetneq p_{i+2}\subsetneq\dots$$ so that $p_{i+1}\cap R\neq p_{i+2}\cap R$. Indeed, in that case we would have $p_{i+1}=pR[X]=p_i$, against the hypothesis on the chain. Conclusion: the chain restricted to $R$ cannot have more than two consecutive equal primes.
- Let $P_1 \subseteq P_2 \subseteq\dots \subseteq P_n\subset R$ be the restricted chain. From the previous point we can't cancel more than two consecutive ideals, and we can assume not to cancel $P_1$ (if it is equal to $P_2$, cancel $P_2$). Then if $n=2m+1$, we can't  cancel more than $m$ ideals; in order to cancel $m+1$ ideals, we should necessarily cancel $P_1$ and $P_n$.

So if $n=2m$, the chain restricted to $R$ becomes of length at least $m$; if $n=2m+1$, the chain restricted to $R$ becomes of length at least $m+1$. In the latter case, using $n$ and $d$ one can write $\frac{n+1}2\le d$, and so $n\le 2d-1$; in the first case one obtains $n\le 2d$.

If I should guess where is the mistake, I would say that a chain of length $2m+1$ can become of length $m$ when restricted (because then we'd get the thesis with the argument in the last paragraph); but  again, if for any ideal that we cancel there must be another ideal equal to it (that we don't cancel), how can be possible that we cancel $m+1$ primes from a chain of length $2m+1$, as $2(m+1)>2m+1$? Thanks for any clarify

Comment: If you have a chain of distinct primes $p_1 \subsetneq p_2 \subsetneq\dots \subsetneq p_n$ in $R[x]$, by intersecting each $p_i$ with $R$, we could get a chain of distinct primes in $R$. Namely,  $q_1\subsetneq q_2\subsetneq\dots \subsetneq q_m$. In this case, we must have $n\leq 2m$. And the desired result follows.

Comment: I mean you have already done almost everything, your dimension of the upper bound inequality should be $n-1$ in the maximal chain you found.

Comment: @Minglingmaster I didn't understand the observation in the last comment. My main problem is the second paragraph of the post, where I find that $n\le 2d$ instead of $2d+1$, and I don't even see how it could be $n=2d+1$

Comment: As I said in my first comment. I picked a maximal chain in $R[x]$ which means that $n$=dim$R[x]+1$, and dim$R\geq m-1$. Since we have $n\leq 2m$, we are done